# WEKA - Error on assigning Instances to kmeans.buildClusterer

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka

I'm pretty new in Weka framework. So far i find it pretty simple and easy to use and understand but i'm facing some problems i cannot understand. I'm trying to cluster a dataset from an csv file. I got a class that clusters the dataset using kmeans and as far as i read in the Weka's wiki (http://weka.wikispaces.com/) the class works fine. The only problem was that it was reading an arff file and i needed to read from a csv file. So far so good. The problem is when i assign the instances from the dataset to kmeans.buildClusterer(data) method. Then i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pentaho/packageManagement/PackageManager 
        at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.<clinit>(WekaPackageManager.java:86) 
        at weka.core.Utils.readProperties(Utils.java:142) 
        at weka.core.Capabilities.<init>(Capabilities.java:261) 
        at weka.clusterers.AbstractClusterer.getCapabilities(AbstractClusterer.java:179) 
        at weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans.getCapabilities(SimpleKMeans.java:289) 
        at weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans.buildClusterer(SimpleKMeans.java:441) 
        at weka_examples.ClusteringDemo.<init>(ClusteringDemo.java:48) 
        at weka_examples.ClusteringDemo.main(ClusteringDemo.java:70) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.packageManagement.PackageManager 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) 
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) 
        ... 8 more 
Java Result: 1
```

The code is the following:

```
import weka.core.Instances; 
import weka.clusterers.DensityBasedClusterer; 
import weka.clusterers.ClusterEvaluation; 
import java.io.File; 
import weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans; 
import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader; 

/** 
 * An example class that shows the use of Weka clusterers from Java. 
 * 
 * @author FracPete 
 */ 
public class ClusteringDemo { 

    /** 
     * Run clusterers 
     * 
     * @param filename the name of the ARFF file to run on 
     */ 
    public ClusteringDemo(String filename) throws Exception { 
        ClusterEvaluation eval; 
        Instances data; 
        String[] options; 
        DensityBasedClusterer cl; 

        String Origem = filename; 

   // data = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))); 
        // load CSV 
        CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader(); 
        loader.setSource(new File(Origem)); 
        data = loader.getDataSet(); 

        SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans(); 

        kmeans.setSeed(10); 

// This is the important parameter to set 
        kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true); 
        kmeans.setNumClusters(5); 
        kmeans.buildClusterer(data); 

// This array returns the cluster number (starting with 0) for each instance 
// The array has as many elements as the number of instances 
        int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments(); 

        int i = 0; 
        for (int clusterNum : assignments) { 
            System.out.printf("Instance %d -> Cluster %d", i, clusterNum); 
            i++; 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * usage: ClusteringDemo arff-file 
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

        /*if (args.length != 1) { 
         System.out.println("usage: " + ClusteringDemo.class.getName() + " <arff-file>"); 
         System.exit(1); 
         }*/ 
        new ClusteringDemo("Teste/Query1.csv"); 
    } 
}
```

I included the binary file: weka-dev-3.7.10 
Am i missing something important?

Kind regards

Comment: No problem with the code here with "weka-3-6-10" or "weka-3-7-10". Did you give "weka-3-6-10" (the latest *stable* version) a try? Also, do you have some odd Weka `.props` files in your home directory?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I didn't try weka-3-6-10 but i tried a lot other examples and they also throw exceptions in the same method or equivalent. I don't have any other files in my directory. Shall i try Weka-3-6-10?

Comment: It was just a guess (in case of problems, trying the last release declared as being "stable" can hardly be wrong, but it may not make a difference here). There are suprisingly few web search results regarding "penthato package manager" etc. Of course you could try adding the JAR from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pentaho.pentaho-commons/pentaho-package-manager/1.0.9 to the classpath, but as long as it is not clear what this is good for (and what is causing the error) this is still only guesswork. Maybe someone else knows "THE" answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to answer this question. It turns out that, from version 3.7.2, weka core is much more compact, meaning that some packages i need were not present in the weka-dev.
The solution is simple: add to the classpath the weka.jar and not the weka-dev package. Alternatively the missing packages can also be installed http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager%3F

Best regards