# Installing new package in Weka API

Tags: weka, libsvm

Can someone explain to me the steps for including new package in Weka API using the package manager. I am able to install new packages to Weka using the GUI. I am confused how to do so in the API. How do I get the .jar file, which will support the newly added package? I want the weka.jar file to support libsvm.

Comment: Have you gone through this https://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+the+package+manager%3F  ?

Comment: Yes. I have come across this link. I am new to using .jar files. I added my weka.jar file to classpath and executed `java weka.core.WekaPackageManager` command. It gives me some JNI installation error. If the package manager works, can I just copy the .jar file and use it in my eclipse environment?

Comment: Yes u can do it by copying it into your .classpath and run it once

Comment: I am using weka-stable-3.7.9.jar. I have added it to the classpath. I have the latest jdk. On running the WekaPackageManger command, I get the following erro `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pentaho/packageManagement/Package
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
 .....

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031261/weka-error-on-assigning-instances-to-kmeans-buildclusterer

Comment: Fixed it. With the new package manager, we need to import two separate libsvm jar files apart from the weka.jar. Here is what I did: Using the Package Manager installed libsvm package. This downloads a libsvm at /Users/lazyclown/wekafiles/packages/LibSVM. Added the jar file  from there. Also, I had to download a LibSVM jar file from the official LibSVM site. Added both of these to the classpath. Now it's running smoothly.

Comment: The wikispaces wiki no longer exists, here is the new link on how to use the package manager: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/packages/manager/

Comment: Most packages are available as Maven artifacts (search for [group "nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka"](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka)). Here is a link to the [libsvm](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka%20AND%20a:LibSVM) package on Maven Central.